# Magento2.4.3: While importing products, getting this error (The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists)?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I'm trying to import products and while importing I'm getting this error, i have tried this extension for URL rewrite but still getting this error, any temporary fix for this problem[image: mae]

Comment: Have you checked there's no other product with the same URL key, that already exists in your DB? Can you provide the file you're trying to import please?

Comment: yes, I have checked my urk_key column is unique, but I don't know why it is throwing an error, is there any way we can append a keyword at the end of url if it throws this error?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the file you are trying to import. Yes, you can try to just add "-abc" at the end of URL key for a product for which there's an error thrown during import.

Answer (score 1):

it can be problem with `url_rewrite` table. When you want to solve problem, pls check few points:

1. Whether `url_key` in existing products is unique
2. Whether `url_key` in product which you want to import is unique
3. If those points are fine, then you have duplicated entry in `url_rewrite` table. The fastest method to solve it is install `https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites` this module and generate new urls key `php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate` using this command

Good luck